# Estimation transition matrix with low observation count

Tags: r, markov-chains, markov, markov-models

I am building a markov model with an relativ low count of observations for a given number of states.
Are there other methods to estimate the real transition probabilities than the cohort method? Especially to ensure that the probabilities are decreasing with increasing distance from the current state. The pair (11,14) does not behave in that manner and the underlying model wouldn't support this.

```
       2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
  2    4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  3    1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  4    0   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  5    0   0   2  10   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  6    0   0   0   9  53  13   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  7    0   0   0   0  17  42  17   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  8    0   0   0   0   0  21  71  21   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  9    0   0   0   0   0   0  23 102  21   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  23  57  33   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  11   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1  34 142  28   1   3   0   0   0   0   0
  12   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1  28 127  27   0   0   0   0   0   0
  13   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  28 134  27   0   0   0   0   0
  14   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  27  93  20   2   0   0   0
  15   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  23 133  19   0   0   0
  16   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  22 114  20   0   0
  17   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  21 192  19   0
  18   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  21 263  21
  19   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  24 827
```

Thanks

Comment: * I am building this model in R

Comment: http://przyrbwn.icm.edu.pl/APP/PDF/121/a121z2bp08.pdf, in the link they discuss some approaches other than Cohort method.

Comment: Thank you, that will help me :)